# Installing into %AppData%\Microsoft\Addins without deleting Microsoft\Addins folder on uninstall

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I've just been following the [wix tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial)  and I've created a simple installer via Visual Studio 2012.

I'm trying to install an excel addin into the users AppData folder.  Traditionally I provided a batch file which copied the addin to %AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns.  I've replicated that in wix with:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  ... other stuff
  <Directory Id="AppDataFolder" Name="AppData">
    <Directory Id="Microsoft" Name="Microsoft">
      <Directory Id="AddIns" Name="AddIns">
        <Component Id="MyAddin" Guid="...">
          <File Id="MyAddinXla" Source="..\Data\MyAddin.xla"/>
          <RemoveFolder Id="Microsoft" On="uninstall" Directory="Microsoft"/>
          <RemoveFolder Id="AddIns" On="uninstall" Directory="AddIns"/>
          <RemoveFile Name="MyAddin.xla" Id="MyAddinXla" On="uninstall"/>
          <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\AddinKeyPath' Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Now, the wix compiler complains if I don't have the RemoveFolder directives, even though the folders already exist before installing.

When I uninstall the app, the AddIns directory itself is removed (there's nothing else in it).

My question is: should I care that the AddIns folder is removed if empty (will any microsoft app struggle without it), and if I should, how do I tell the installer not to remove it?

Comment: In case you didn't know, `RemoveFolder` only results in the folder being removed if it's empty.

Comment: @TomBlodget thanks, yes I did notice that, I'm just not sure if removing Microsoft/Addins is a good idea or not.